# How can I reorder bootstrap columns on XS screens?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple bootstrap row with two columns:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-push-7">
       This should show on right
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-pull-5">
       This should show on left
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the first row to show on the right and the second row on the left. All of this works, however when the screen size becomes small or extra small, the first column shows up first and second shows up second.

I would like to display second column first and first column second on small and extra small devices. I tried to achieve this with pull-right and pull-left classes but it did not work.

Would appreciate your suggestions.

P.S. I want the divs to stack

Comment: wouldn't you want to be using something like col-xs-pull and col-xs-push?

Comment: The columns stack on xs viewports. Do you want them to stack, or do you want them to be next to one another but switch positions?

Comment: @MattD I want them stacked

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might work if you want the horizontal column ordering reversed:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-push-7">
       This should show on right
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-pull-5">
       This should show on left
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cpdrdehg/).

Comment: Maybe he wanted a stacked version?

Comment: @ManojKumar It sounded like he wanted the order reversed on <= small viewports.

Comment: @alex Which could still mean reversed stacked, or reversed side-by-side.

Comment: @MattD The OP said that he wanted "the first row to show on the right and the second row on the left", except for on small and extra small devices.  Granted the code that they posted doesn't do this, but mine does.  I've updated the answer to be a little more specific about what my code does.

Comment: @alex He says later, "I would like to display second column first and first column second on small and extra small devices." With OPs code the columns stack, so the question is: does OP want them in that order stacked, or side-by-side? Is the current output correct aside from the order, or is the output completely incorrect for both the presentation *and* the order? That's what OP needs to clarify.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys, I do want them to stack on top of each other for anything less than MD. @alex

Answer (score -1):

If you do want these to stack rather than being side by side like the comments are talking about.
And if you want the second dive to show on top of the stack then you would do it something like this. Show and hide to swap between divs/blocks.
Here is a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ng5zj0fq/)** I set the media breakpoints low at 320px.

```
<div class="row showhide1">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-push-7 col-sm-5 col-sm-push-7 col-md-5 col-md-push-7 bg-primary">
       This should show on right on larger views
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-xs-pull-5 col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5 col-md-7 col-md-pull-5 bg-info">
       This should show on left on larger views
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row showhide2">
    <div class="col-xs-12 bg-primary">
        Was on right, now on top on smaller views
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 bg-info">
        This should show on left on smaller views

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to avoid having two sets of same content. Is there no other way?

Comment: Hi there, there is another way... just don't push/pull in the first place and just have the divs in the right order rather than swapping them to the other sides with push and pull. Any reason why you need to do that?